# How does Haskell-vim-now replace certain expressions with unicode characters?

Tags: haskell, vim, unicode

I'm using the excellent [haskell-vim-now](https://github.com/begriffs/haskell-vim-now) package to enhance gvim on Ubuntu. It's great, and customizable, but I want to try building up my own `.vimrc` from scratch to get more comfortable with the editor's more advanced features. I'm struggling to replicate one of haskell-vim-now's features, even after reading haskell-vim-now's `.vimrc`.

It replaces certain expressions with unicode characters to show code more mathematically. For example, one might define a lambda expression in haskell with `\`. This would show up in the editor as `λ`. To be clear *the underlying text is still `\`, only the in-editor display is changed*. Does anyone know how to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is called "conceal". It is a built-in feature but that haskell-vim-now package uses [another third-party plugin](https://github.com/enomsg/vim-haskellConcealPlus) to provide haskell-specific rules.

That plugin is listed in the package's vimrc at [line 79](https://github.com/begriffs/haskell-vim-now/blob/master/.vimrc#L79).

See `:help conceal` for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Haskell-vim-now uses [haskellConcealPlus](https://github.com/enomsg/vim-haskellConcealPlus), which is installed as a bundle in its `.vimrc`.

It can be achieved in other editors that support ligatures by using [Hasklig](https://github.com/i-tu/Hasklig).